# Can you reference a single entry from a single field in an access query using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to learn vba for a system I am developing for the company I work for. However, it has been a steep learning curve. Specifically, I want to automate a series of MS Access 2013 reports rather than key in a new id# for the report each time I want to send it out.

I can pull a list of all the id# I need reports for by a query, but I was wondering if there is some way for vba to sequentially walk through each record, assign the id# to a variable (and/or put it in a unbound control that is in the form that currently controls the report), and then produce a pdf of the report (eventually I'd like to auto-email the report as well.

Really, this is a ton for me to do, but it could save countless hours in the future if successful. So far, all I can do is print out a report to pdf from vba, but I have to key in the data into the form, and this isn't saving any time.

Any ideas would be great. I am very new to vba.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There should be plenty of examples of code for `DAO` `Database.Openrecordset()` and `Recordset.Movenext` loops on the net.

Try creating a global `IDNo` variable (a `Public` or `Friend` variable in a database module header) and an `ID()` function in the database module that returns the value of the IDNo variable, and using that function in the report's query to filter the records.

For each loop through your `Recordset`, assign the appropriate datum to the `IDNo`  global variable, and execute `DoCmd.OpenReport`.

You should get one report for each `record` in your `recordset`, filtered on ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec1 as Recordset
Dim rec2 as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
set rec1 = db.OpenRecordset ("Select IDNum from TableWithIDs")

Do While rec1.EOF = False
set rec2 = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from ReportTable Where IDNum = " & rec1(0) & "")

... Process report based on the query results of rec2

set rec2 = nothing
rec1.MoveNext
Loop
```